# Array values not being displayed in drop down list

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

i want to display elements of an array in a drop down list.I am using document object model inside a for loop to do this but keep getting an error that the drop down list is null

Javascript Code

```
var str="-1,40,42,43,44,46,47,54,90,890,987,1235,4555,12434,122223,788998,789444,2147483647";
var n =new Array();
n = str.split(",");
alert(n);

var select=document.getElementById("rec");
for(i=0;i< n.length;i++)
{
    var opt=n[i];
    var el=document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent=opt;
    el.value=opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
}
```

HTML code

```
<div id="rec1" name="rec1" style="display:none">
     <p>Select the Record number of the record you want to edit&approve&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         <select id="rec"  name="rec" >
            <option value="def" selected="selected">Select choice</option>
         </select>
</div>
```

The TypeError i'm getting is that "select is null"

Comment: I guess you have script tag before the select tag.

Comment: post complete code pls

Comment: I made a fiddle that works, I took `display:none` out. http://jsfiddle.net/SG8Zw/

Comment: Why do you initialize `var n = new Array()` if you're just going to assign a different array in the next line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that the Javascript is executing after the DOM has loaded. To ensure this, most people will write their code in a `window.onload` function, like this:

```
<script>

window.onload = function(){
    var str = "-1,40,42,43,44,46,47,54,90,890,987,1235,4555,12434,122223,788998,789444,2147483647";
    var n = new Array();
    n = str.split(",");

    var select = document.getElementById("rec");
    for (i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
        var opt = n[i];
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        select.appendChild(el);
    }
}
</script>
```

Since your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SG8Zw/) seems to work okay, this is likely the problem. Otherwise, there must be some other code of yours that is interfering with the script. Also note that I have removed the style `display:none` on the fiddle.

Comment: thanks a lot!!!!!i put my code inside a window onload function and it's working properly...:)